# What is best XSLT XPath performance in my scenario?

Tags: xml, performance, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a question about XSLT XPath performance. If we look in the following example.

Which of following options has best performance:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//cd">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="//catalog/cd">
```

**XML data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <cd>
            <title>Still got the blues</title>
            <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</root>
```

**XSLT stylesheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Which has the best performance?**

(I have made this smaller easier example, in my real case I have much more complex data structure)

Comment: Your input document is not well-formed XML. Please edit your question.

Comment: In general, an explicit path will be more efficient than one using the descendant axis.

Comment: I will try to use that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible answer to this question is "it depends on the processor". As a rule you should avoid using `//` un-necessarily, but a clever processor may be able to optimise simple `//something` absolute paths (e.g. using a hash table to look up nodes by name) to be faster than the fully specified `/root/catalog/cd`.

You have to profile your specific processor on your specific data.

Comment: Thank you for your input, my real case is more complex. I guess i can do some performance testing and meassure the time it takes and so on. I will also try to avoid using `\\\`

Comment: @MattiasAndersson Please do not forget to accept an answer (in my opinion, this answer is more useful in your case) - or edit the question to clarify what exactly your "real case" is.

Comment: Thank you @MathiasMüller I accepted this answer. But also thanks for yours as well, good answer base on my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Measure it and see. You shouldn't even start investigating ways of improving performance until you have a measurement framework in place. If you have a measurement framework in place, you wouldn't need to ask the question here, and if you don't have one, you have no way of evaluating the answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your input document is not well-formed; one of the `cd` elements is not closed and there is no single outermost element that contains everything else. Assuming the following input:

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Still got the blues</title>
            <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</root>
```

Now, regarding your question: You should use neither `<xsl:for-each select="//cd">` nor `<xsl:for-each select="//catalog/cd">`. In fact, you should not use `xsl:for-each` at all, there is no reason to use it here. You're better off learning how to write separate templates to do the job, like in the following stylesheet.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title|artist">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While it is true that the output is exactly the same and that `xsl:for-each` could be used, `for-each` is a heavily overused construct, especially by beginners - in places where templates would have been more elegant.

---

> Wich has the best performance?

This question has nothing to do with XSLT, it has to do with XPath expressions embedded in XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//cd">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^      XSLT
                      ^^^^        XPath
```

Usually, XPath expressions should avoid the `//` (`descendant-or-self::`) axis. You should always  be reluctant to use `//`, and only use it if the structure of the input document is truly unpredictable or if the elements you'd like to target are arbitrarily nested.

Comment: "*you should not use xsl:for-each at all, there is no reason to use it here.*" And there is no reason not to use it here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know, I tried to make it clear that it _is_ a valid approach here, but that templates are often neglected when using them would have been a more elegant solution. Looking at the OP's code, my impression is that perhaps they do not know about separate templates. In what way would you like me to edit my answer?

Comment: "*In what way would you like me to edit my answer?"*" I don't know. I think that on the whole, both issues have been made sufficiently clear.

Comment: Thank you for your input, i am aware of using templates, but i tried to simplify my example as much as possible.